# Iterar json con Angular2

Tags: json, angular

Estoy intentando iterar el `json` resultante de una llamada pero no encuentro manera. El `json` lo leo de la siguiente manera:

```
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/traerDatos.php').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(result => this.result = result);
```

Y lo guardo en una variable tal que así.

```
    let resultado = this._recogeIdService.consultaId();
```

A partir de aquí no se como tratar la variable resultado para que me muestre el contenido.
Un ejemplo del `json` resultante según la consola de Chrome es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Has probado así?

```
this.resultado.forEach((obj) => {
  console.log(obj.id);
})
```

Comment: He tenido que quitar el .suscribe del http.get y dejar solo el .map, aparte al llamar el objeto le he tenido que poner la clave fija  y quedaba así: obj['marchena14'].id, y es correcto. Muchas gracias, hoy en dia tanta información hace que no veamos ni lo más sencillo.